# How to include linux driver source files in a kernel module written in C?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, nvme

I am currently writing a linux kernel module that needs to include a file from the linux driver source code. The particular file I am trying to include is: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/nvme/host/nvme.h

But the `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` directory does not contain the `drivers` folder. I tried doing `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)` but that also does not include the driver header files. My Makefile looks like this:

```
obj-m += hello_world.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I then tried to get a full kernel checkout of the kernel version closest to my kernel version (I couldn't find the exact source code for my kernel version.) I pointed my Makefile to use that version but then when I try to insert the kernel module, it throws `Invalid module format` error and `dmesg` shows `no symbol version for module layout`. My source directory does contain the `Module.symvers` file but it still throws this error. I believe this error could be resolved if I somehow use my current linux source.

So, what's the best way to get the driver header files and use them in a kernel module. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `apt`. In such case you can get the correct source for your kernel simply enabling source repositories (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121041) or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) to know how) and then getting the source code of the package:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

After this, you will have the following files in the current directory:

```
linux-XXX/
linux_XXX.tar.xz
linux_XXX.dsc
linux_XXX.orig.tar.xz
```

The first one is a folder containing the correct source code for your installed kernel. You'll then be able to `#include` the header you need for your module.

Comment: Thanks Marco for your answer. Your approach successfully got me my linux distro's source code. Although, when I try to compile and load my kernel module, it still shows the same error - `Inavlid module format`. Any leads?

Comment: @BasimSahaf have you tried doing a full clean and then rebuilting from scratch? Try compiling a simple hello world module that only has an init and exit function and does nothing, see if that compiles and inserts correctly (also, try with `modprobe` if `insmod` does not seem to work). If that does not work, add the steps that you made to reproduce the error.

Comment: I figured out why it is happening. When I do `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`, it gets a different version than my current kernel version. So, since the two kernel versions are different, therefore  I am not able to insert the kernel module. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @BasimSahaf Not sure, `uname -r` should get the currently running kernel version. I don't see how something different could happen normally.